# Rolling sum for a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the rolling sum for the *growth* column for the following sample data which can be found here [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cfb3491bce974908e4126528d578ad6f)

The output should look like,

```
Growth  RollingSum  TMonth  TYear
511       511       AUG     2019
79        590       SEP     2019
-6        584       OCT     2019
0         584       NOV     2019
-4        580       DEC     2019
45        625       JAN     2020
-1        624       FEB     2020
7         631       MAR     2020
-22       609       APR     2020
-6        603       MAY     2020
-20       583       JUN     2020
0         583       JUL     2020
```

My attempt is as follows. I am only getting the total for values in the *Growth* column

```
 SELECT r1.Growth,  sum(r2.Growth) AS rolling_total ,r1.Month,r1.Year 
    FROM Report AS r1 JOIN Report AS r2
        ON r1.Month = r1.Month
    GROUP BY r1.Month;
```

The above gives me the result as,

```
Growth  RollingSum  TMonth  TYear
511      583         AUG    2019
79       583         SEP    2019
-6       583         OCT    2019
0        583         NOV    2019
-4       583         DEC    2019
45       583         JAN    2020
-1       583         FEB    2020
7        583         MAR    2020
-22      583         APR    2020
-6       583         MAY    2020
-20      583         JUN    2020
0        583         JUL    2020
```

I want to avoid using procedures,cursors or functions if at all possible. I am using **mysql 8.0.17**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SUM()` window function but with the correct ordering.
This ordering:

```
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(`TMonth`, '%M'), `TYear`
```

is wrong because `DATE_FORMAT()` with these parameters returns `NULL`, so you simply sort by Year.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e5d306216a09a9d639fe5fd34d8ab50).
It is coincidental that you get correct results.

The correct ordering is:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(TYear, TMonth, '01'), '%Y%b%d')
```

So use this:

```
SELECT
  Growth,
  SUM(Growth) OVER (ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(TYear, TMonth, '01'), '%Y%b%d')) RollingSum,
  TMonth,
  TYear
FROM Report
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29c08fd545ad5e9327e7a7f044e238fa).
Results:

```
> Growth | RollingSum | TMonth | TYear
> -----: | ---------: | :----- | ----:
>    511 |        511 | AUG    |  2019
>     79 |        590 | SEP    |  2019
>     -6 |        584 | OCT    |  2019
>      0 |        584 | NOV    |  2019
>     -4 |        580 | DEC    |  2019
>     45 |        625 | JAN    |  2020
>     -1 |        624 | FEB    |  2020
>      7 |        631 | MAR    |  2020
>    -22 |        609 | APR    |  2020
>     -6 |        603 | MAY    |  2020
>    -20 |        583 | JUN    |  2020
>      0 |        583 | JUL    |  2020
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using mysql 8 use [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html)n SUM

DATE_FOMAT are not working, so you need STR_TO_DATE

> ```
> CREATE TABLE roll_month (
>   `Growth` INTEGER,
>   `RollingSum` INTEGER,
>   `TMonth` VARCHAR(3),
>   `TYear` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO roll_month
>   (`Growth`, `RollingSum`, `TMonth`, `TYear`)
> VALUES
>   ('511', '511', 'AUG', '2019'),
>   ('79', '590', 'SEP', '2019'),
>   ('-6', '584', 'OCT', '2019'),
>   ('0', '584', 'NOV', '2019'),
>   ('-4', '580', 'DEC', '2019'),
>   ('45', '625', 'JAN', '2020'),
>   ('-1', '624', 'FEB', '2020'),
>   ('7', '631', 'MAR', '2020'),
>   ('-22', '609', 'APR', '2020'),
>   ('-6', '603', 'MAY', '2020'),
>   ('-20', '583', 'JUN', '2020'),
>   ('0', '583', 'JUL', '2020');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `Growth`
> ,  SUM(`Growth`) OVER(  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01-',`TMonth`,'-',`TYear`), '%d-%M-%Y')  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)  RollingSum  
> , `TMonth`, `TYear` 
> FROM roll_month
> ```
>
> ```
> Growth | RollingSum | TMonth | TYear
> -----: | ---------: | :----- | ----:
>    511 |        511 | AUG    |  2019
>     79 |        590 | SEP    |  2019
>     -6 |        584 | OCT    |  2019
>      0 |        584 | NOV    |  2019
>     -4 |        580 | DEC    |  2019
>     45 |        625 | JAN    |  2020
>     -1 |        624 | FEB    |  2020
>      7 |        631 | MAR    |  2020
>    -22 |        609 | APR    |  2020
>     -6 |        603 | MAY    |  2020
>    -20 |        583 | JUN    |  2020
>      0 |        583 | JUL    |  2020
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=65221f4199af3b4e7afd295074ad4a7a)*

Answer (score 1):

With the values and names that i took from [your table](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4696f0cc1ef44666c83719704039ed2), this cross join would give you the output you want way more easy:

```
select r1.Growth, r1.TMonth, TYear,
(@s := @s + r1.Growth) as RollingSum
from Report r1 cross join
    (select @s := 0) p;
```